# Magnify document

Tags: fontsize, scaling

I've written about a hundred or so lectures in LaTeX, all of which include a separate preamble document for consistency and ease of maintenance.  Now that I have a SMARTboard in my classroom, I would like to import the lecture PDFs into the SMARTboard's software (called Notebook).  I can drag-and-drop the PDFs into Notebook and it imports them automatically, which is great.  But the documents are sized all wrong for the SMARTboard.  Everything is too small to be legible by the class.

So I need to magnify the documents (by about 140%) so that the resulting PDF is sized appropriately for the SMARTboard.  And I'd like to do this magnification from within the preamble so that all of my lectures are magnified consistently.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I tried the `\mag` command, but I get an "incompatible magnification" error, and besides, I've since learned that using `\mag` is discouraged.
2. I tried `\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont`, but it has to be after `\begin{document}` instead of in the preamble, and it doesn't affect things like `\section` and `\subsection`.  So that's no good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use `\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont}`?  As for the `\*section` stuff, that sounds like you should redefine for the (new) preamble.

Comment: So you are not concerned about the change in layout? Is a modification in the document dimensions an option?

Comment: I've already modified the document dimensions so that the PDF pages match Notebook's page size.  The type is simply too small, is all.

Answer (score 17):

Try magnifying the whole document using the `pgfpages` package from the `pgf` suite. The following code will magnify the pages from an a4paper to an a3paper scaling the page appropriately.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=80pt,right=80pt,top=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a3paper]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You can also specify an explicit paper height and paper width using:

```
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[physical paper width=13in,physical paper height=26in]
```

Comment: "A word of warning: using pgfpages will destroy hyperlinks." (From the PGF manual.)

Answer (score 6):

`\mag` should be used at the very beginning; just for demostration purposes, I use 2500.

```
\mag=2500
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=210truemm,paperheight=297truemm,margin=1.5truecm}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

`pdfinfo` says

```
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
```

and of course you can put whatever size you want.

[image]

Comment: `\mag` should work within the preamble as well (just before geometry).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It's less risky if it's at the top, but if you want to live dangerously ... :) Anyway it must be used with care as it's not officially supported by LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

As Yiannis and Werner already suggested, you can "zoom in" by simply decreasing the paper size.  If your projector has an aspect ratio of 4:3 you could add something like

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=400pt,paperheight=300pt]{geometry}
```

to your common preamble.  You might want to adjust the margins as well.  Just consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=400pt,paperheight=300pt, left=20pt, right=20pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

(Actually that's more of a comment to Yiannis's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to post one.)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following document, alternatively commenting and uncommenting the `pgfpages` lines in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer} % 11pt by default, slides are 12.80 x 9.60 cm
\usetheme{warsaw}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
\title{A Title}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks to Andrew Stacey for prompting me to verify that my earlier assumptions were valid (they weren't).

---

Original version (not as good a solution):

Assuming we're talking about beamer slides for your document, and if you need overlays, this will get you part of the way:

```
\documentclass{beamer} % 11pt by default, slides are 12.80 x 9.60 cm
%\documentclass[20pt]{beamer} % 20pt option, slides need to be 23.27 x 17.45 cm
%\geometry{papersize={23.27cm,17.45cm}}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\title{A Title}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Original beamer slide (with default settings):

[image]

Modified beamer slide (with larger paper size):

[image]

It's certainly not perfect (unscaled navigation buttons, for one), but it's a start. There are some other margins and lengths to be scaled that I've not identified yet.

But if you don't need overlays, you should be able to use pgfpages to make handouts with a given paper size (section 21.1 of the [beamer manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)). Something like (untested):

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout[landscape,a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use pgfpages with overlays?  (I haven't tested it, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.)

Comment: I can't explain it, and I can't presently find any documentation supporting my original assertion. As you suspect, there's no problem with it working. Updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is certainly true there can be problems with pgfpages due to things getting moved about on pages, but that's about hyperlinks and absolute positioning.  There's warnings about that in the pgf manual - maybe that's what you were thinking of.  I think your example will need to be `\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[landscape,a4paper,border shrink=5mm]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the traditional

```
\documentclass{article}
```

interface, `\normalsize` defaults to `10pt`. Opting for

```
\documentclass[14pt]{scrartcl}
```

`\normalsize` is `14pt` - a 40% increase - with (somewhat) proportional increase in other font options as well. In fact, within the KOMA-script class, `14pt`/baselineskip implies

- `\tiny` @ `5pt`/`6pt` increases to `6pt`/`7pt` (20% larger);
- `\scriptsize` @ `7pt`/`8pt` increases to `8pt`/`9.5pt` (~14% larger);
- `\footnotesize` @ `8pt`/`9.5pt` increases to `10pt`/`12pt` (25% larger);
- `\small` @ `9pt`/`11pt` increases to `12pt`/`14pt` (~33% larger);
- `\normalsize` @ `10pt`/`12pt` increases to `14pt`/`17pt` (40% larger);
- `\large` @ `12pt`/`14pt` increases to `17pt`/`22pt` (~42% larger);
- `\Large` @ `14.4pt`/`18pt` increases to `20pt`/`25pt` (~39% larger);
- `\LARGE` @ `17.28pt`/`22pt` increases to `25pt`/`30pt` (~45% larger);
- `\huge` @ `20.74pt`/`25pt` increases to `29.86pt`/`35pt` (~44% larger); and
- `\Huge` @ `24.88pt`/`30pt` increases to `35.83pt`/`40pt` (~44% larger)

The same holds for

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
```