# How to magnify with a factor < 1 in plain Tex?

Tags: plain-tex, magnification

I want to reduce the size of everything in a document to read it on a specific device.

I tried to use

```
\magnification=833
```

as 1/1.2 * 1000 = 833 and I think that Knuth uses this kind of formulas to get to the numbers used as magnification factors.

But I get the following error:

```
! Incompatible magnification (833);
 the previous value will be retained (1000).
```

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58059/250119

Comment: I get no error with the simple `\magnification=833` command. You cannot set the magnification factor after a page has been shipped out.

Comment: @user202729 The question you are referring to is about LaTeX, not Plain TeX

Comment: @egreg Thank you, apparently I just needed to switch two macros, the order matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\mag` factor can be set only once for a document and the job of `\magnification` is to set `\mag` and restore the page dimensions to use `true` units.

TeX implicitly sets `\mag` to 1000 at the first shipout operation, if it hadn't been set before. So both

```
\magnification=1000
\magnification=833
```

and

```
abc\eject
\magnification=833
```

are illegal and will raise the error you mention.